# How can I get the version number of an selected item in tridion?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

How can I get the version number of an selected item (Component/Page)

I am using the below code

```cs
VersionedItemData verinfo=csClient.Read(<selecteditemid>, new ReadOptions()) 
                                                         as VersionedItemData;
<selecteditemid> = Component/Page id
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Version` and `Revision` properties are available in `FullVersionInfo`, so you have to cast `VersionInfo` of your item:

```
((FullVersionInfo) verinfo.VersionInfo).Version
```

Answer (score 1):

VersionItemData.VersionInfo.Version will return you the latest version number.

Comment: Hi Bappi, Thanks for quick respponse. Could you please provide it again-  i am unable to find VersionItemData instead we have VersionedItemData.